# From everywhere to everywhere in ArcGIS using Closest Facility did not solve all possible routes

Tags: network-analyst, network, closest-facility

I am building from-everywhere-to-everywhere routes in ArcGIS Network Analyst using OpenStreetMap Data. I have 189 points that I want to connect with all possible other facilities. I ran this using the Closest Facility Tool in Network Analyst, by loading 189 facilities and 189 incidents, and trying to find 189 closest facilities for my incidents. Ideally, I should have 35532 routes, if excluding self-loop. However, after dissolving the network, fixing topology, snapping my facilities and incidents to the network data, allowing U-turns, increasing search radius to 1500m, I kept only having 18559 routes solved. Some of my incidents were only connected to one or two other facilities. What could have gone wrong?

Comment: Try increasing the search radius further, even to 30k. Do you get any messages in the log (e.g. non-traversal element errors?) Have a look here : https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/troubleshooting-network-analyses.htm

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I tried it, and it did not work. all the facilities and incidents were located, I increased search tolerance to 30,000 meters. Still came up with 18,559 routes.